# using an iconpicker to select font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I want to use this icon picker : https://fonticonpicker.github.io/ and I want to use it with font awesome, but I can't display my icons in the picker.
I've made this jsfiddle to test it : https://jsfiddle.net/anwes87q/

```
var fnt_icons_categorized = {
                "Accessibilité": ["fab fa-accessible-icon", "fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting", "fas fa-assistive-listening-systems", "fas fa-audio-description", "fas fa-blind", "fas fa-braille", "fas fa-closed-captioning", "far fa-closed-captioning", "fas fa-deaf", "fas fa-low-vision", "fas fa-phone-volume", "fas fa-question-circle", "far fa-question-circle", "fas fa-sign-language", "fas fa-tty", "fas fa-universal-access", "fas fa-wheelchair"],
                "Monnaie": ["fab fa-bitcoin", "fab fa-btc", "fas fa-dollar-sign", "fas fa-euro-sign", "fab fa-gg", "fab fa-gg-circle", "fas fa-lira-sign", "fas fa-money-bill-alt", "far fa-money-bill-alt", "fas fa-pound-sign", "fas fa-ruble-sign", "fas fa-rupee-sign", "fas fa-shekel-sign", "fas fa-won-sign", "fas fa-yen-sign"],
                "Date & heure": ["fas fa-bell", "far fa-bell", "fas fa-bell-slash", "far fa-bell-slash", "fas fa-calendar", "far fa-calendar", "fas fa-calendar-alt", "far fa-calendar-alt", "fas fa-calendar-check", "far fa-calendar-check", "fas fa-calendar-minus", "far fa-calendar-minus", "fas fa-calendar-plus", "far fa-calendar-plus", "fas fa-calendar-times", "far fa-calendar-times", "fas fa-clock", "far fa-clock", "fas fa-hourglass", "far fa-hourglass", "fas fa-hourglass-end", "fas fa-hourglass-half", "fas fa-hourglass-start", "fas fa-stopwatch"],
            };

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#fip').fontIconPicker({
    source: fnt_icons_categorized,
  }); // Load with default options
});
```

The icons are from font awesome 5.0.8 from https://gist.github.com/migliori/60154172ba0eea70e3c0dd4c3b5d82d0
I'm using this specific version because the icons are categorized

The code is simple stupid so I think I'm missing something obvious, but can't find what it is.

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include the code from your fiddle here on Stack Overflow so that people don't have to go to a different site just to answer your question...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's working well in the stack snippets with the same code :/

Comment: You need to include the css in the correct order.  Your jsfiddle includes the fonts first - this one includes them last: https://jsfiddle.net/318wb7dc/

Comment: @freedomn-m that's it, thank you, but I think I would have never find that out by myself !